# read txt file and parse text

Tags: php, javascript, parsing

I'm attempting to parse a text file but I'm not sure of the best approach and practice to do so. Using PHP I thinking of loading the entire file into a string or should I do it line by line? Im comfortable with a JavaScript method as well just not as familiar!

Should I search for the the needle inside the haystack using strstr? Or what other methods are good for parsing a simple text file that is consistent.

Note the only data I want out of the text file(temp_log.txt) is:

```
 Date: 07/07/2013   Time: 00:57:00.208      21 C
 Date: 07/07/2013   Time: 00:57:02.029      25 C
```

temp_log.txt:

```
 =>MET RTD

 SEL-2411                                 Date: 07/07/2013   Time: 00:57:00.208
 DEVICE

 INTRTD01   21 C
 INTRTD02 Open
 INTRTD03 Open
 INTRTD04 NA
 INTRTD05 NA
 INTRTD06 NA
 INTRTD07 NA
 INTRTD08 NA
 INTRTD09 NA
 INTRTD10 NA

 =>

 =>MET RTD

 SEL-2411                                 Date: 07/07/2013   Time: 00:57:02.029
 DEVICE

 INTRTD01   25 C
 INTRTD02 Open
 INTRTD03 Open
 INTRTD04 NA
 INTRTD05 NA
 INTRTD06 NA
 INTRTD07 NA
 INTRTD08 NA
 INTRTD09 NA
 INTRTD10 NA

 =>
```

Comment: Regular Expressions may be your best bet with this one.  They would be very simple with this format.

Comment: If you're using PHP anyway: Parse the log file with php (e.g. regex); convert the result to [JSON](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php); pass the JSON to your JS client. Among other things, this would have the advantage of being able to access the data with AJAX. Also, the useless rest of your log file wouldn't need to be transferred to the client.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example how to get Date and Time and Temperature with ReGex in PHP

```
<?php
$text = 
"=>MET RTD

 SEL-2411                                 Date: 07/07/2013   Time: 00:57:00.208
 DEVICE

 INTRTD01   21 C
 INTRTD02 Open
 INTRTD03 Open
 INTRTD04 NA
 INTRTD05 NA
 INTRTD06 NA
 INTRTD07 NA
 INTRTD08 NA
 INTRTD09 NA
 INTRTD10 NA

 =>

 =>MET RTD

 SEL-2411                                 Date: 07/07/2013   Time: 00:57:02.029
 DEVICE

 INTRTD01   25 C
 INTRTD02 Open
 INTRTD03 Open
 INTRTD04 NA
 INTRTD05 NA
 INTRTD06 NA
 INTRTD07 NA
 INTRTD08 NA
 INTRTD09 NA
 INTRTD10 NA

 =>";

// split text to lines 
$lines = explode("\n", $text);

// find date, time and temperature
$all = array();
$date = "";
$time = "";

foreach( $lines as $line ) {
    $number = preg_match('#Date: ([^ ]+).*Time: ([^ ]+)#', $line, $result);
    if( $number > 0 ) { 
        $date = $result[1]; 
        $time = $result[2]; 
    }

    $number = preg_match('# (\d+) C#', $line, $result);
    if( $number > 0 ) { 
        $all[] = array($date, $time, $result[1]); 
    }
}

// print all results
foreach($all as $element) {
    echo "Date: ", $element[0], "   Time: ", $element[1], "      ", $element[2], " C", PHP_EOL;
}

?>
```